# Failed to pass the value of an instance variable to another from within the same class (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, methods, instance-variables

this is my code.

```
class Dog

    attr_accessor :name
    attr_reader :breed, :age

    def initialize(name, breed, age)
        @name = name
        @breed = breed
        @age = age
        @distance_in_kms = []
    end

    def walk(distance_in_kms)
        @distance_in_kms << {distance: distance_in_kms}
    end

    def walked_distance 
       @walked_distance = @distance_in_kms.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:distance]}
    end

    def display_walks
        puts "#{@name} has had #{@distance_in_kms.length} walks and walked #{@walked_distance} kms today:"
        @distance_in_kms.each do |each_walk|
            puts "#{each_walk[:distance]} km"
        end
    end 

    #overriding to_s to print a meaningful representation of a class
    def to_s
        return "Dog: breed-#{@breed} name-#{@name}"
    end
end

doggo = Dog.new("Roy", "Labrador", 8)
doggo.walk(3)
doggo.walk(5)
doggo.walk(1)

puts doggo.name = "Dang"
puts doggo.breed
doggo.display_walks
```

The result I have is this

```
Dang
Labrador
Dang has had 3 walks and walked  kms today:
3 km
5 km
1 km
```

The expected value before kms should be 9, the sum of each walk in a day. Obviously, I have done something wrong with the `walked_distance` method. I was trying to pass the value of array `@distance_in_kms` into `@walked_distance`, but it didn't work, the return value was nil.But what can I do to fix the problem and get expected results? Thank you!!

Comment: Your distance hashes don't seem to have key `:amount`

Comment: Yeah, I changed that to `:distance`, still doesn't work

Comment: Change `#{@walked_distance}` string to `#{walked_distance}`. Instance variable from the method never was called in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call the method to update the `@walked_distance`, for example:

```
def display_walks
    walked_distance # <------ This line
    puts "#{@name} has had #{@distance_in_kms.length} walks and walked #{@walked_distance} kms today:"
    @distance_in_kms.each do |each_walk|
        puts "#{each_walk[:distance]} km"
    end
end
```

Or change the `walked_distance` method and call it directly from the string interpolation:

```
def walked_distance 
   @distance_in_kms.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:distance]}
end

def display_walks
    puts "#{@name} has had #{@distance_in_kms.length} walks and walked #{walked_distance} kms today:"
    @distance_in_kms.each do |each_walk|
        puts "#{each_walk[:distance]} km"
    end
end
```

---

Off topic, just a small change to evaluate:

```
@walked_distance = @distance_in_kms.values.sum
```

Comment: That's absolutely amazing! Thank you so very much~~~

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> puts "#{@name} has had #{@distance_in_kms.length} walks and walked #{@walked_distance} kms today:"
> ```

But you never call the code to calculate `@walked_distance`. Either update it when you add a new walk or calculate total distance here (by calling `walked_distance`, for example)

Answer (score 0):

I could've done this right at the beginning too:

```rb
class Dog

    attr_accessor :name
    attr_reader :breed, :age

    def initialize(name, breed, age)
        @name = name
        @breed = breed
        @age = age
        @distance_in_kms = []
        @walked_distance = []
    end

    def walk(distance_in_kms)
        @distance_in_kms << {distance: distance_in_kms}
        @walked_distance = @distance_in_kms.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:distance]}
    end

    def display_walks
        puts "#{@name} has had #{@distance_in_kms.length} walks and walked #{@walked_distance} kms today:"
        @distance_in_kms.each do |each_walk|
            puts "#{each_walk[:distance]} km"
        end
    end 

    #overriding to_s to print a meaningful representation of a class
    def to_s
        return "Dog: breed-#{@breed} name-#{@name}"
    end
end

doggo = Dog.new("Roy", "Labrador", 8)
doggo.walk(3)
doggo.walk(5)
doggo.walk(1)

puts doggo.name = "Dang"
puts doggo.breed
doggo.display_walks
```

or use class methods to create a counter then try to link it to the instances(It's a very long way though)

Indeed, understanding variable scope is a real struggle for a beginner. Anyway, much appreciation for anyone who answered my question. Thank you!